# JavaScript image path forward slash removed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the correct path which then I can set that for image url in JavaScript. I'm trying with this approach:

```
<IMG BORDER="0" width="100" height="50" style="margin-right:5px;" ALIGN="Left" SRC='+ decodeURIComponent(data.logofilename)+'>
```

This is what I'm getting for value:

[image]

And this is how the value is coming from the database:

> \Images\Logos\a08a9656-9a0f-414d-8bcd-f8515e1260a3_logocolortextbelow.jpg

How can I tackle this?

Comment: @David It's there, just wasn't formatted correctly. On a side note, what does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: Those are backslashes.  Try with forward slashes instead.

Comment: Well I would assume that the decoder is treating the \ characters as escape characters, but `\I` and `\L` and `\A` don't mean anything, so it must be removing them. As user3553031 said, try forward slashes instead (`/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of server is sending you the data?  You're server needs to send the data back with those characters escaped such as -

```
\\Images\\Logos\\a08a9656-9a0f-414d-8bcd-f8515e1260a3_logocolortextbelow.jpg
```

Comment: sql server: REPLACE(com.LogoFileName, '~\', '\') as ImageFilePath,

Answer (score 0):

For now, try

```
decodeURIComponent(data.logofilename).replace('images', '\Images').replace('Logos', '\Logos\')
```

Comment: same response with your approach

Answer (score 0):

Replace `decodeURIComponent(data.logofilename)` with `decodeURIComponent(data.logofilename.replace("\\", "/"))`.